# Find textbox by Name (ID) C# for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I wanted to know if it is possible to find a text box by name in C# for ASP.NET.

For example `for` in this method:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++)
{
    ("txtName" + i).Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Actually it has to be working for ASP.NET, forgot to mention that

Comment: I've removed the comment about duplicate, thanks for the update

Answer (score 3):

You can use FindControl to search for a control by ID. Remember that the FindControl will work within the container only. In your case, if your controls are within a container, do a FindControl within that container.

This link gives you more details on the topic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Assuming that you are using the default template, there is a Master page which has a MainContent or body container. You need to get a reference to that and then search for controls within it.

```
var container = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
var control = container.FindControl("txtNaam1");
```

If the controls lie within a different container, you need to get a reference to that container and search within it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. The textbox i'm searching for isn't in a master page. But in a .aspx file. This is exactly what my textbox looks like: <asp:TextBox ID="txtNaam1" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: @Bilal075 Is it inside a panel or some other container?

Comment: It isn't  the only container I can imagine is the contentplaceholder (which is in this case <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">)

Comment: @Bilal075 Replace the "MainContent" in my code with "ContentPlaceHolder1" and check

Comment: How can I paste the code in <code></code> inside a comment? Sorry, i'm new to this forum :P

Comment: @Bilal075 You are still using this.FindControl, you should be using container.FindControl

Comment: instead of `this.FindControl("txtNaam" + i)` it should be `container.FindControl("txtNaam" + i)`

Comment: Wahao, thank you so much! I didn't notice it myself. Forgot to search inside the result I just received. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`Page.FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is what you want.

Comment: It gives me an error message, and if I add an else statement it'll just enter there (the problem seems to be finding the element by name since it enter the else statement).

Comment: Can you post more information about the page and the controls you want to change? Are they within a container?

Comment: Sure, So this is my textbox. <asp:TextBox ID="txtNaam1" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:TextBox>. It is in a table, on a master page. Not inside anything, just a div.

Comment: I think your textboxes are inside a container. I won't edit my answer, as Praveen Paulose already covered it in his answer, so I'll upvote him and direct you to his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

in code behind:

```
(this.FindControl("txtName" + i) as TextBox).Visible = true;
```

Comment: What error you get? Maybe you don't have a textBox with that Id?

Comment: I do, the error message i'm getting: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in OpdrachtASP.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: That suggests that either the control wasn't found, or it wasn't a `TextBox`.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find the textbox i'm looking for. Not sure why though (since the id matches with the one i'm looking for)

Comment: Can you show the definition of the textBox in the aspx page?

Comment: The idea behind this whole thing is, that whenever I change the selectedindex on a ddl (drop down list). The textboxes visibility will change to true / false (depends on which selected). All the textboxes have been named in this order: txtName1, txtName2, etc etc. So I wanted to create a loop which changes the visibility to true of the counter I set (for example counter = 6, it should set all the textboxes visibility to true untill txtName6 has been reached).

Comment: Can you just show the definition of one textBox? Maybe you missed something

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old, but I have also faced the similar issue.
For me, the textbox was inside an update panel. So I have used the below code to find it in aspx.cs.

```
var txtBox = updPanelPage.FindControl(btn.CommandArgument) as TextBox;
```