# Need to pass current user to gridview using stored procedure and control parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create an orientation for newly signed in accounts. I have the `AspNetUsers` table that Identity populates to by default, but I have created `Roles` and `Accounts` tables that use the username as a foreign key. Basically, if I can pass that first variable it should return 1 user record that I can make the wizards vies join to but this is what I get instead.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not find control 'hdn_httpuser' in ControlParameter 'httpuser'.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'hdn_httpuser' in ControlParameter 'httpuser'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'hdn_httpuser' in ControlParameter 'httpuser'.]
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.ControlParameter.Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control) +553
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.UpdateValue(HttpContext context, Control control) +70
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.UpdateValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +137
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.LoadCompleteEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) +59
> System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
> System.Web.UI.Page.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e) +138
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5909

`Codebehind aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WorldsStrongestProgrammer2024App
{
    public partial class Orientation : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        // Inherited From Master

        // # User Checking Variables
        public Orientation()
        {
        }

        public string httpuser;

        public string GetHttpUser()
        { 
            var a = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            httpuser = a;

            return httpuser; 
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetHttpUser();
            }

            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                GetHttpUser();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WebPage aspx:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_httpuser"> 
    <columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="hdn_httpuser" runat="server" Value="<%: httpuser %>"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_aspuser" DataSourceID="sql_aspuser" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataKeyNames="HttpUser">
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sql_aspuser" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Documents_SQLConn %>" SelectCommand="sLoginWizardOrientation_Step1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter controlID="hdn_httpuser" PropertyName="Text" Name="httpuser" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sLoginWizardOrientation_Step1 
    (@httpuser varchar(max) = '%')
AS
    SELECT 
        [Id],
        [Hometown],
        [Email],
        [PhoneNumber],
        [UserName] AS HttpUser
    FROM 
        [db_a84118_maindocuments].[dbo].[AspNetUsers]
    WHERE 
        UserName = @httpuser
```

Comment: The error says " Could not find control 'hdn_httpuser' in ControlParameter 'httpuser'".  I do not see the code that would return this error.  You grideview uses ID to identify the controls.  I do not see any c# code that is trying to locate a control.  Make sure any code that is trying to find a control uses the ID to get the control.  Your c# code is trying to find the user that made the connection, not the control.

Comment: Please see again. I've passed the user variable as the value of 'hdn_httpuser'       
                              
`<asp:TextBox ID="hdn_httpuser" runat="server" Value="<%: httpuser %>"/>

<asp:ControlParameter controlID="hdn_httpuser" PropertyName="Text" Name="httpuser" Type="String" />`

Comment: why does it default to `%`? That makes me think you're expecting wildcard behavior, but your where clause is an `=`

Comment: @Xedni I dont think this matters at this point. Of course in production it will be required because im trying to pass 1 or 0 records... Can you help me pass the value of httpuser  in the hdn_httpuser control to the parameter? The gridview gv_aspuser is using the value from gv_httpuser to start the first trip to my database

Comment: You just posted the HTML on the webpage on the server.  It is not the c# client code that is parsing the HTML.  The error is coming from the client code trying to parse the HTML and get the control (textbox) with the ID "hdn_httpuser".  The error says "Could not find control 'hdn_httpuser".  The error is from client code parsing the HTML.

Comment: @jdweng Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735694/find-textbox-by-name-id-c-sharp-for-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Well, ignoring that you have a public method of that page class with the same name as the page class?

I suggest that you dump the use of the in-line SQL data source on the web page. The reason for this is loss of control when the SqlDataSource "runs", and worse is when your code behind runs to setup some values/parameters to be used by the SqlDataSource (You can't with ease control when the SqldataSource control fires).

So, you now on a wing and a prayer as to when the SqlDataSource source runs, but has your code behind run before the GridView has attempted to use the SqlDataSource source based on some values in code behind (you don’t know!)?

So, with all this "auto magic" occurring, the end result is loss of control as to when things run on the web page.

The simple matter is you in near ALL cases are far better off to NOT use the SQL data source in the markup. Often, I will use the wizards to create the GridView, and that does result in a SqlDataSource in the markup. However, the VERY next thing I do is REMOVE the SqlDataSource, and move that data pull to code behind.

The above advice will thus save you world poverty and much suffering. So, using the builders and wizards to help out is fine, but REMOVE the SQL data source(s) created by such wizards (at least if you going beyond any kind of "training wheels" code).

So, even when using builders and wizards to create a GridView?
I strong suggest dumping and removing the SqlDataSource control that was placed in the markup.

As noted, it is VERY difficult to control when that SqlDataSource control triggers, and often it will trigger/run BEFORE your code behind. And worse yet is when code behind attempts to mess with, and change values that the SqlDataSource consumes, and you "hope" such values have been set before the SqlDataSource has run.

So, that code behind to set some of the parameters? You can't control when the page load and running of the SqlDataSource has occurred already.

Solution: Don't use the SqlDataSource when you have code values and parameters from code behind. Such code may well not yet have run, but the SqlDataSource has already been used and run.

Ok, so with above in mind, then our code becomes this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }


    void LoadGrid()
    {

        string sUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("sLoginWizardOrientation_Step1");
        cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@httpuser", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sUser;

        gv_aspuser.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        gv_aspuser.DataBind();  

    }
```

Note now how we have 100% control of the data pull and setting of the GridView.

Of course, it can fast become VERY tiring to write SQL and connection code over and over. Hence this global helper routine is rather helpful.

```
public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

With above we have 100% control over when the data is pulled, and 100% control of setting the parameters.

Just remember to remove the SqlDataSource setting in the GridView's markup.